# create a large dataset using Python

Tags: python, dataset, schema

I want to create a large dataset (that conforms to a given schema) using Python. Is there a nice way to specify the schema (datatype & length of each of the fields), and let Python create about 100,000 observations for me? Any nice tools already there?

I am familiar with Python...hence would like to stick with it. if there is one using Bash or any other way, please let me know as well.

Thanks!
PD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably check out the [fake-factory](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-factory) package.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks KT. Will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this:-

https://github.com/sanju51/Generate-large-Dataset-dynamically-in-Python

SPEED:- 100000 records in 5 seconds(10 columns)
USAGE:- python generate_dataset.py -i Metadata.csv -f sample.csv -nrec 100000 -d ',' -hdr Y